# Include .as files using actionscript3 and https

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, https, include

I've been using .as files on my Flash site using

```
include "myFile.as";
```

my files are all on the same server and under the same domain.

I installed an SSL security certificate and want to start using the 'https' protocol.

I know my files are called with the https protocol when I call a new URL but how do I include my .as files?

Answer (score 0):

[`import`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#import) and [`include`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/statements.html#include) are compile-time calls to use code available at the time of compilation.  Those files have no bearing on a compiled swf, which means you probably don't want them on your webserver.

To be succinct: `include` has zero relationship with networking.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to some other languages (like php or js), ActionScript 3 is not an interpreted language, meaning that the sources files (the .as, but also the .fla and .swc) cannot be run as is. They must be compiled in executable form : the .swf file(s).

As said by Atriace, `import` and `include` are called at compile time (when you compile/export your swf), while network operation, like file download, is done at execution time. That means that include is done way before file download, and that you cannot include a dynamically downloaded file.

From what you are trying to do, I guess that you want to download and execute a different code depending on the situation. A good way to do this is to you a "plugin system".

Basically, in addition of your main swf file, you have a bunch of other swf files whose goal is to be loaded by the main swf and to interact with it. This is done via the `Loader` class. If all your plugins swfs are made to interact with the main swf in the same way (that can and probably should be ensured by using an interface), then each of them can execute their own content while being managed in the same way by the main swf.